# How to hide Scrollbar thumb?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a way to hide the Scrollbar thumb, for example in this image Notepad does not have a thumb for both Scrollbars:

[image]

I have tried to set `SCROLLINFO.nPage` to `0` but it did not work.

---

**Edit:** I am talking about a control Scrollbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `SetScrollInfo`, set the `SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL` flag in the `fMask` field. The scrollbar will then be disabled (and the thumb hidden) if the scroll bar's parameters make the scroll bar unnecessary.

However that technique only works for the non-client window scrollbars. If you want to disable a control scrollbar you need to do it yourself using `EnableWindow()`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"if the scroll bar's parameters make the scroll bar unnecessary"*. Is it for example when `SCROLLINFO.nPage` is set to the scroll range?

Comment: @johnny92 Yes, basically, if `(nMax - nMin) < nPage` is true.

Comment: In that case, I have tried to do that, but the Scrollbar was still enabled: `scrollInfo.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_RANGE | SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL; scrollInfo.nMin = 0; scrollInfo.nMax = 639; scrollInfo.nPage = 640;`.

Comment: Try making `nPage` 641 (or 5000), scroll bar maths are a little kooky.

Comment: I have tried both values, and the Scrollbar is still enabled (and the thumb visible).

Comment: I just realised you are talking about a separate scrollbar control; although the docs don't say, it may be that `SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL` only works on the standard non-client scrollbars. If you have a separate control you can just disable it manually using `EnableWindow()`.

Comment: `EnableWindow()` worked :-) It hides the thumb regardless of what value I set for `scrollInfo.nPage`.

Comment: I'll add this to the answer.